# Mostrar imagem quando passar o mouse sobre uma div - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-hover

No site citado tem um efeito de que quando você passa o mouse sobre o link ele aparece uma imagem.

> https://www4.benner.com.br/

```css
 .ul_ajudamos{ margin: 20px 0 0 20px; list-style:none; padding-right: 500px ; } .link_ajudamos{ position: relative; /* Para que a imagem não saia fora do link */ display:block; padding:5px; border:1px #999999 solid; background-color: #CCCCCC; text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; padding-right: 200px; } .link_ajudamos:hover{ background-color:#999999; border-radius: 20px; } .link_ajudamos span{ display:none; /* Aqui você define que todo SPAN que estiver dentro de um A estará invisível */ } .link_ajudamos:hover span{ display:block; /* Aqui você diz que ao passar o mouse sobre o link, colocar um display no span dentro desse link */ position:absolute; /* Para você poder posicionar ao queira, sem quebrar o layour em volta */ top: 0px; /* Para ficar na mesma altura do link */ left: 100%; /* Empurra a imagem para fora do link, ficando ao seu lado */ border:1px #CCCCCC solid; /* Estilo extra, lembrando que você pode colocar qualquer estilo nesse elemento */ }
```

```html
<ul class="ul_ajudamos">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link1<span><img src="img/img1.jpg"/></span></a>
    
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link2<span><img src="img/img2.jpg"/></span></a>
            </li>
    
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link3<span><img src="img/img3.jpg"/></span></a>
            </li>
    
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link4<span><img src="img/img4.jpg"/></span></a>
            </li>
    
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Gostaria de reproduzir o mesmo efeito, mas com o código atual que fiz, a imagem não aparece no mesmo local, alguém tem algum exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: Seu código está certo, precisa apenas remover as `<li>` que estão dentro da primeira `<li>` e colocar dentro da `<ul>`

Comment: @Vinicius.Silva acho que foi só um erro de digitação dela, repare que a últi LI tem duas tags de fechamento e a primeira LI não fecha depois do </a>

Comment: Exato, eu errei na digitação.
Eu quero manter as imagens aparecendo no mesmo lugar sabe, e não que elas acompanhem o link

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade você quer que a imagem que está dentro da cada `li` apareça numa div fora do menu ao passar o mouse.

Com essa estrutura de HTML, só com CSS você não irá conseguir fazer isso. Tem que criar uma div que irá receber as imagens e nela colocar a imagem 1 e ir alterando com `mouseover` usando JavaScript. Terá que remover também todo este bloco do CSS:

```
.link_ajudamos:hover span{
   ...
}
```

Como a pergunta não mostra o seu layout real, um exemplo básico seria como abaixo. Veja:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   var links = document.querySelectorAll(".ul_ajudamos li");
   for(let x=0; x < links.length; x++){
      
      links[x].onmouseover = function(){
         
         document.querySelector("#imagem img").src = this.querySelector("img").src;
         
      }
      
   }
   
});
```

```css
.ul_ajudamos{
   margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
   list-style:none;
   padding-right: 500px;
}

.link_ajudamos{
   position: relative; /* Para que a imagem não saia fora do link */
   display:block;
   padding:5px;
   border:1px #999999 solid;
   background-color: #CCCCCC;
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   padding-right: 200px;
}

.link_ajudamos:hover{
   background-color:#999999; border-radius: 20px;
}

.link_ajudamos span{
   display:none; /* Aqui você define que todo SPAN que estiver dentro de um A estará invisível */
}

#imagem{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#imagem img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagem"><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"/></div>
<ul class="ul_ajudamos">
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link1<span><img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"/></span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link2<span><img src="https://onlinejpgtools.com/images/examples-onlinejpgtools/coffee.jpg"/></span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link3<span><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/534af30be4b0589a6dce3444/t/5384c47fe4b0cfdce9f468db/1401210076669/thCAQN1GI0.jpg"/></span></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="link_ajudamos">+ link4<span><img src="https://baixaki.com.br/imagens/2013/10/30/30152755351-t100.jpg"/></span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Então, está vendo que a imagem acompanha o link, eu queria fazer aparecer em um ponto fixo todas, igual no exemplo que mandei do site. As imagens aparecem todas no mesmo lugar

Comment: É que a pergunta não ficou clara. A impressão que dá é que vc quer que as imagens apareçam dentro dos links. Dá uma olhada na minha resposta que alterei.